# Bigram frequencies in text

Tags: string, fastest-code, python

## Introduction

This challenge is about producing a code to count the frequency of bigrams in a text. A bigram is two consecutive letters in a text. For instance 'aabbcd' contains the bigrams aa, ab, bb, bc, cd once each. Counting bigram frequencies is super useful in cryptography. In a brute force algorithm, this code may be called many times and as a result, must be optimised to run quickly.

## Challenge

- Challenge is in Python 3 and NumPy can be used.
- The input will be a string of text (no spaces or punctuation). The output will be a NumPy array that is 26x26 or a list of lists that would be equivalent to the NumPy array. The first letter of the bigram is the row index and the second letter is the column index. The values in the array represent the frequency of that particular bigram.
- The fastest code wins. I will measure the time it takes for the code to run 10,000 times on my computer (2015 Aspire F15 Intel i3 2.0GHz 4GB RAM).

## Input

This is the input that I will test the code on

```
'WERENOSTRANGERSTOLOVEYOUKNOWTHERULESANDSODOIAFULLCOMMITMENTSWHATIMTHINKINGOFYOUWOULDNTGETTHISFROMANYOTHERGUYIJUSTWANNATELLYOUHOWIMFEELINGGOTTAMAKEYOUUNDERSTANDNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUWEVEKNOWNEACHOTHERFORSOLONGYOURHEARTSBEENACHINGBUTYOURETOOSHYTOSAYITINSIDEWEBOTHKNOWWHATSBEENGOINGONWEKNOWTHEGAMEANDWEREGONNAPLAYITANDIFYOUASKMEHOWIMFEELINGDONTTELLMEYOURETOOBLINDTOSEENEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVENEVERGONNAGIVEGIVEYOUUPWEVEKNOWNEACHOTHERFORSOLONGYOURHEARTSBEENACHINGBUTYOURETOOSHYTOSAYITINSIDEWEBOTHKNOWWHATSBEENGOINGONWEKNOWTHEGAMEANDWEREGONNAPLAYITIJUSTWANNATELLYOUHOWIMFEELINGGOTTAMAKEYOUUNDERSTANDNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYE'
```

## Output:

This is the expected output

```
[[ 0.  0.  4.  0.  0.  1.  8.  0.  0.  0.  8. 11. 10. 21.  0.  2.  0. 14.
   7. 10.  0.  0.  0.  0. 10.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  6.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  6.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  6.  0.  6. 10.  0.  0.  5.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  3.  8.  0.  0.  0.
   1.  1.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [11.  2.  0.  0.  8.  0.  5.  1.  0.  0.  4. 11.  0. 13.  0.  0.  0. 53.
   7. 10.  0. 39.  2.  0. 17.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  1.
   0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.  0.  1.  2.  0.  2.  0.  9.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 52.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 3.  0.  0.  0.  8.  0.  0.  0.  4.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  5.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  5.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  2.  5.  1.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  4. 12.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   1.  5.  0.  9.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  8.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  7.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 7.  0.  1.  1.  7.  0.  0.  0.  9.  0.  0.  9.  1.  0.  3.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 9.  0.  0.  0.  5.  3.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [49.  0.  0. 26. 39.  0. 13.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0. 47.  8.  0.  0.  0.
   2.  3.  0.  0.  2.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  7.  0.  1.  0.  0.  3.  0.  0.  3.  2. 44.  9.  0.  0.  2.
   6.  7. 49.  1. 16.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  6.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  6.  2. 38.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  7.  0.  0.  0.
   5. 13.  7.  0.  0.  0.  6.  0.]
 [ 9.  4.  0.  0.  7.  1.  0.  2.  2.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  3.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  6.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  0.  0.  8.  0.  1. 10.  4.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  7.  0.  0.  1.
   5.  4.  0.  0.  2.  0. 19.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  6.  6.  0.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  1.  3.  0. 24.  0.  7.  0. 10.
   2.  2.  9.  0.  2.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. 49.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.  9.  0.  0.  3.  3.  0.  0.  0.  0.  8.  1.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  3.  0.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  6.  0.  6.  0.  5.  0.  0.  0.  0.  6. 43.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
   0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66833) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main, You should provide some specifications for your computer, so that people are aware on what their code will be tested. Additionally, I'd suggest mentioning exactly what a bigram is, just for completeness sake. Finally, does it have to be a numpy array, or can it just be a list of lists?

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my question with the suggested changes.

Comment: Is pandas available?

Comment: Any python library you want but the output has to be as specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + numpy (0.359 seconds)

```python
def f(IN):
    a = np.array([IN.encode()],"S").view(np.uint8)-ord('A')
    c = np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index((a[:-1],a[1:]),(26,26)),None,26*26)
    return c.reshape(26,26)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VTRattAEHz3V4i8WCqOISmEYujD2VpLV592w90pQhgTVFshglgWipzWX@/uqW6c/oFLBQLd7M7O3By65tA97@rPx2rb7NrOq/fb5uAVr17dDAYSva/eMAMNSMZqgRFoY0nRA@SULpAyG4NOFRiBoaGQpJinSs0oSaRNAK3JYmFlYmOJC4kRzZmWUapCtBFYhs1cUyIwJzcoSnP5LTU2E4jCglLcHVMmkzmAYnpE1opELJx4iqHzwroID0wlpkSy95XenyEFlpGQMjxjOuWXeACTQzCgXcu5fBKY6fyMGZFHROE0hzPmDAolgafEaT8j45oLBUHM4n5Hc9KG48KIqzoGoa2ZAiCXeTvT1JE0WCIT55ZYRFqJRoaQwZT5bpYLsOdE5ALEDE6xRyJx0u5wejv3ytEZkS5kYRYJfMwuJLTOcQJ/NKcMh6wKcDkJXqqTv1fv3i7gwP/pH@Z/dTIcHDflk/fkSwwmA4@fgi/auhkXbVsc/KXEcVmvd5vSD1ajK3MVjN@q8ofPDfuq7r4E17t24w/FMOi569/c7xVT9nXn2trirXx53O5fuuqxqjflT98vlpPrm9WoWN5MVsHIv70b3d4FwQh3dclfn3jRD2vLbt/W3nrclq/PRVOeGgfHpmVpv7ccHH8B)

**UPDATE** better array construction (first line in function) thanks @tsh! **(0.332 seconds)**

```python
a = np.frombuffer(IN.encode(),"u1")-ord('A')
```

**/UPDATE**

Comment: Wow! This algorithm is blisteringly fast compared to any of my attempts.

Comment: Maybe `np.frombuffer(IN.encode('ASCII'), dtype=np.uint8) - 65` is a bit fater

Comment: @tsh Probably, though I doubt above noise level. Btw. 'ASCII' seems to make it slower on my machine by what seems to be a constant offset. Presumably interpreter overhead, because explicitly passing the default encoding has a similar effect.

Answer (score 3):

## Python (133 chars) (16.1 seconds)

```
import numpy as np
i=input()
o=np.zeros((26,26))
for b in[(ord(i[j])-65,ord(i[j+1])-65)for j in range(len(i)-1)]:o[b]+=1
print(o)
```

This code runs in O(n) time, where n is the length of the string.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: To measure your code, I created a function that included lines 2-4. The import was not included and the print was removed to avoid crashing the software. I replaced input() with the string.

Comment: code length is 129 not 133. Also welcome to CCSE :)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 304.1µs

#### `src/main.rs`

```rust
// extern crate ndarray;
use ndarray::Array2;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::Instant;


fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let result = convert_string("WERENOSTRANGERSTOLOVEYOUKNOWTHERULESANDSODOIAFULLCOMMITMENTSWHATIMTHINKINGOFYOUWOULDNTGETTHISFROMANYOTHERGUYIJUSTWANNATELLYOUHOWIMFEELINGGOTTAMAKEYOUUNDERSTANDNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUWEVEKNOWNEACHOTHERFORSOLONGYOURHEARTSBEENACHINGBUTYOURETOOSHYTOSAYITINSIDEWEBOTHKNOWWHATSBEENGOINGONWEKNOWTHEGAMEANDWEREGONNAPLAYITANDIFYOUASKMEHOWIMFEELINGDONTTELLMEYOURETOOBLINDTOSEENEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVENEVERGONNAGIVEGIVEYOUUPWEVEKNOWNEACHOTHERFORSOLONGYOURHEARTSBEENACHINGBUTYOURETOOSHYTOSAYITINSIDEWEBOTHKNOWWHATSBEENGOINGONWEKNOWTHEGAMEANDWEREGONNAPLAYITIJUSTWANNATELLYOUHOWIMFEELINGGOTTAMAKEYOUUNDERSTANDNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYENEVERGONNATELLALIEANDHURTYOUNEVERGONNAGIVEYOUUPNEVERGONNALETYOUDOWNNEVERGONNARUNAROUNDANDDESERTYOUNEVERGONNAMAKEYOUCRYNEVERGONNASAYGOODBYE");
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    println!("Time elapsed in convert_string() is: {:?}", duration);

    println!("[");
    for row in result.genrows() {
        print!("[");
        let last_index = row.len() - 1;
        for (index, item) in row.iter().enumerate() {
            if index == last_index {
                print!("{:3}", item);
            } else {
                print!("{:3},", item);
            }
        }
        println!("]");
    }
    println!("]");
}

fn convert_string(input: &str) -> Array2<i32> {
    let mut transition_counts = HashMap::new();
    let mut prev_char = None;
    for c in input.chars() {
        let current_char = c as i32 - 'A' as i32;
        if let Some(prev) = prev_char {
            *transition_counts.entry((prev, current_char)).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }
        prev_char = Some(current_char);
    }
    let mut result = Array2::zeros((26, 26));
    for (&(i, j), &count) in transition_counts.iter() {
        // println!("{:?}",count);
        result[(i as usize, j as usize)] = count;
    }
    result
}
```

#### `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "rust_hello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]

ndarray = "0.15"
```

#### Build and running

```
# win10 environment

$ cargo build --release   
$ target\release\rust_hello.exe
Time elapsed in convert_string() is: 304.1µs
[
[  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  1,  8,  0,  0,  0,  8, 11, 10, 21,  0,  2,  0, 14,  7, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  6,  6,  0,  6, 10,  0,  0,  5,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  8,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0]
[ 11,  2,  0,  0,  8,  0,  5,  1,  0,  0,  4, 11,  0, 13,  0,  0,  0, 53,  7, 10,  0, 39,  2,  0, 17,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0]
[  2,  2,  0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  0,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 52,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0]
[  3,  0,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0]
[  1,  0,  0,  2,  5,  1,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  4, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  5,  0,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  7,  0,  1,  1,  7,  0,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0,  9,  1,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0]
[  9,  0,  0,  0,  5,  3,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[ 49,  0,  0, 26, 39,  0, 13,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, 47,  8,  0,  0,  0,  2,  3,  0,  0,  2,  0,  1,  0]
[  0,  1,  0,  7,  0,  1,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  3,  2, 44,  9,  0,  0,  2,  6,  7, 49,  1, 16,  0,  0,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  1,  0,  0,  0,  6,  2, 38,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  0,  5, 13,  7,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0]
[  9,  4,  0,  0,  7,  1,  0,  2,  2,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0]
[  5,  0,  0,  0,  8,  0,  1, 10,  4,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  7,  0,  0,  1,  5,  4,  0,  0,  2,  0, 19,  0]
[  1,  0,  6,  6,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  1,  3,  0, 24,  0,  7,  0, 10,  2,  2,  9,  0,  2,  0,  1,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0, 49,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  2,  0,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0,  3,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  0,  6,  0,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6, 43,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
[  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), ~180µs on PC, 1000µs on TIO

```
res=Normal@SparseArray[
   Normal@Counts[
     Partition[
      Flatten[Position[ToUpperCase /@ Alphabet[], #] & /@ 
        Characters@data], 2, 1]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVVNa9tAEL3rVywp9BQo7bUEvJZGq62lHbMfFsL2YZsKbPAXknror3dnFWEllKQJ9sWgNzNv3ryZxXvfbeq977aP/vzLd/7hrgQNCo3VXAnQxmKOC6jQzRSWNgPtcjBcJQYTlDx1eR5jUUhbgLKmzLiVhc3kKlIzqQSmVFiiyxNlBVgKmFRjwVWFgUq4Sv5wxpZcKW4hzyk7w1IWKUBO5QJXkbW84LMgwKkk6KHeChZUjFQkZK/NzUcoB0tIgqUaMb2KHP0iUVB5AgZ0SBoThhaxrkbM8EogJtMKRoz0kEyeSyCezPUsJUWDOQp4nPVzpagN2aYERXUGXFszBVAUpqGmjopIjwaLaLLKIjWSViojEyhhSgyBLVjZVwkMRqoShgUIXoTmYU3BHxI1zwMBYTLYzc2sgOcuJqhsUF2ECfuuU4IT6guXyYjn3V6@5WTgea@X/zr53OdbqAk8t1Aj6J4X8PLqLvo@tH7y5@kArlz/KhoO4LL@/zykV57RKvrgQ3rF7gvPlXbT3m@g5sJz9fL793WDU@x53lZz9/3c1O2DOjZ7v5uYk2/amjeN/7OMGGMDHB9/H7q2Rxib@6bbdtvjYfhm6c53XX1Yzo/tE26P7nSqm9i3NfsyYXx32vifdbdc37NPa/Y5YEMpY/HGN/6xq5t2Ev4IKOXbPfu6Xq/P82Z76CYk7vwX)

[image]

Tested for now just on Mathematica 12 on Windows 7 Lenovo laptop, 4x1.5Ghz 4Gb
Sure Mathematica 13 on more powerful PC takes tens of µs